# Duplicate code in IF else blocks...how do I make it shorter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

```
if ((e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["LanguageID"].ToString()) == null) 
                {
                    Int32 LangID = -1;
                    string QuesTypeID = com.Encrypt(TypeID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
                    string LanguageID = com.Encrypt(LangID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
                    string QuesID = com.Encrypt(ID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
                    string PID = com.Encrypt(radGridQues.CurrentPageIndex.ToString(), com.KeyCode.ToString());
                    Response.Redirect(ROSDAAB.Constants.SiteURL + "editQues/" + "QuesID/" + QuesID + "/" + PID + "/" + QuesTypeID + "/" + LanguageID);
                }
                else   
                {

                    Int32 LangID = Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["LanguageID"].ToString());
                    string QuesTypeID = com.Encrypt(TypeID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
                    string LanguageID = com.Encrypt(LangID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
                    string QuesID = com.Encrypt(ID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
                    string PID = com.Encrypt(radGridQues.CurrentPageIndex.ToString(), com.KeyCode.ToString());
                    Response.Redirect(ROSDAAB.Constants.SiteURL + "editQues/" + "QuesID/" + QuesID + "/" + PID + "/" + QuesTypeID + "/" + LanguageID);
                }
```

**[EDIT]
Thats duplicate code in IF else blocks...how do I make it shorter ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use ToString()?

```
if (e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["LanguageID"] == null)
```

Just be aware of the underlying type

```
Int32 LangID = (Int32)e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["LanguageID"];
```

So as for shorter:

```
int LangID = e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["LanguageID"] != null ? (int)e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["LanguageID"] : -1;
string QuesTypeID = com.Encrypt(TypeID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
string LanguageID = com.Encrypt(LangID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
string QuesID = com.Encrypt(ID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
string PID = com.Encrypt(radGridQues.CurrentPageIndex.ToString(), com.KeyCode.ToString());
Response.Redirect(ROSDAAB.Constants.SiteURL + "editQues/" + "QuesID/" + QuesID + "/" + PID + "/" + QuesTypeID + "/" + LanguageID);
```

If the null check does not work, try `!Convert.IsDBNull(),` if your values are from a data source.

```
int LangID = !Convert.IsDBNull(e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["LanguageID"]) ? (int)e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["LanguageID"] : -1;
```

Comment: ok will change that too..Could you plz help me shorten the code? thnx

Comment: ok I tried removing that..the way I have implemented below is working.

Answer (score 3):

```
Int32 LangID = -1;
if (e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["LanguageID"] != null) 
{
    LangID = Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["LanguageID"].ToString());
}
string QuesTypeID = com.Encrypt(TypeID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
string LanguageID = com.Encrypt(LangID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
string QuesID = com.Encrypt(ID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
string PID = com.Encrypt(radGridQues.CurrentPageIndex.ToString(), com.KeyCode.ToString());
Response.Redirect(ROSDAAB.Constants.SiteURL + "editQues/" + "QuesID/" + QuesID + "/" + PID + "/" + QuesTypeID + "/" + LanguageID);
```

Here's what I did here:

- extract LangID out of the if, set it to the default value of -1, and only update it if LanguageID is not null.
- place the common part that was duplicated in your if/else clauses after the if check, since the else is no longer needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

You below code this:-

```
   bool isOk = String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["LanguageID"].ToString());    
   Int32 LangID = isOk ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["LanguageID"].ToString()); ;
   string QuesTypeID = com.Encrypt(TypeID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
   string LanguageID = com.Encrypt(LangID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
   string QuesID = com.Encrypt(ID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
   string PID = com.Encrypt(radGridQues.CurrentPageIndex.ToString(), com.KeyCode.ToString());
   Response.Redirect(ROSDAAB.Constants.SiteURL + "editQues/" + "QuesID/" + QuesID + "/" + PID + "/" + QuesTypeID + "/" + LanguageID);
```

Comment: You haven't addressed the problem of repeating the long line for assigning the LangID variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the ternary operator to reduce repeats:

```
var tempLangId = e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["LanguageID"];
Int32 LangID = tempLangId == null ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(tempLangId);
```

Answer (score 1):

string QuesTypeID = com.Encrypt(TypeID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
        string LanguageID = com.Encrypt(LangID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
        string QuesID     = com.Encrypt(ID.ToString(), com.KeyCode);
        string PID = com.Encrypt(radGridQues.CurrentPageIndex.ToString(), com.KeyCode.ToString());

```
    Int32 LangId = -1;

    if ((e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["LanguageID"].ToString()) != null) 
    {
                Int32 LangID = Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["LanguageID"].ToString());
    }


    Response.Redirect(ROSDAAB.Constants.SiteURL + "editQues/" + "QuesID/" + QuesID + "/" + PID + "/" + QuesTypeID + "/" + LanguageID);
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I tried this ..it worked

```
 if ((e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["LanguageID"].ToString()) == String.Empty)
```